# How do I stop Yoast from using first image it finds on a page as its og:image?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I think I understand that the behaviour's expected to prioritise from a given individual page's overriding image, to the first image it can scrape from a page, to the site's default fallback image (this being the lowest priority).

I somehow disabled the "first image it can scrape" bit though on a test build of a site, and I'm wondering how I can replicate that? As far as I can tell, all the settings as far as Yoast between my environment and production are the same, and I'm really confused what's causing the difference.

But to keep clear, I want all pages across the site to use the fallback image set in Yoast's social settings by default, only ever replacing it if a specific page is given an override image; and so I'm trying to stop Yoast from ever using images it finds from a page.

I feel like I must be blind to've not been able to find another thread/question that addresses this – that, or what I'm doing doesn't make sense for whatever reason?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/custom-open-graph-tags/

Comment: The article's covering how to set the override image, no? Unless I'm confused. I'm wanting to not have to do that, but have the og:image still use the WordPress site's default Facebook Image instead of using an image it finds from the actual page. There's a follow-up link by the end: https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/811e92b11e5277977047d44ea81ee9d4. But I don't think any of them are what I'm looking for, the remove_action() functions just remove og tags entirely.

Comment: If you always want the same default image, then you can just turn off the open graph tags in Yoast and add your own tags to the page templates `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/path-to/default-image.jpg" />`